# Testing interactions in stateless react component using shalllow rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a stateless component which I want to test

```
const PageSizer = ({itemsPerPage, onItemsPerPageChange}) => (
    <form>
       <label>Items Per Page </label>
       <select value={itemsPerPage} onChange={(e) => {onItemsPerPageChange(e.target.value) }}>
           <option value="10">10</option>
           <option value="25">25</option>
           <option value="50">50</option>
           <option value="100">100</option>
       </select>
   </form>)
```

I want to test that when the select value is change it triggers the onItemsPerPageChange callback with the option value.

I have found through trial and error that renderIntoDocument doesn't work as its a stateless component.

Using shallow rendering how would I test this?

I have come up with

```
it('should call onItemsPerPageChange when select value is changed', () => {

    var spy = expect.createSpy();

    var shallowRenderer = TestUtils.createRenderer();
    shallowRenderer.render(<PageSizer onItemsPerPageChange={spy}  />)
    var result = shallowRenderer.getRenderOutput();

    var select = result.props.children[1]
    TestUtils.Simulate.change(select, { target: { value: 25 } });

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(25)
});
```

The spy is never called though. Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it working by calling the onChange prop directly

```
select.props.onChange({ target: { value: 25 } })
```

as I noticed they did with the click event in [https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/test/**tests**/ReactTestUtils-test.js](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/test/__tests__/ReactTestUtils-test.js)